# In a REST API paginated resources: what would you return when a client request a page exceeding the maximum page number?

Tags: rest, pagination, http-status-codes

Let say we have only 30 products and a REST API with QueryString parameters used for pagination. In the exemple below `pagesize` is the number of resources per `page`.

```
api/products?page=1pagesize=10
```

What do you prefer to answer when the request is asking for a page over the max page like the following?

```
api/products?page=125&pagesize=10
```

1. 400 - Bad Request?
2. 404 - Not Found?
3. 200 - Ok (with empty result)?
4. 204 - No Content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with **Not Found**, since the request's syntax is perfectly fine. [See the status code explanations](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the RFC I didn't anticipate it could be such in an human readable format :) According to this Bad Request seems not to be appropriate. I then read a bit more on this RFC but you could be accepted answer in a short delay. What do you think about 204 - No Content

Comment: 2xx is meant for successful, 4xx for unsucessful calls. So in this case I would say that a query for a non-existing ressource is unsuccessful and should therefore lead to a 4xx response. And among those, 404 seems to fit best

Comment: 204 should not return a message body. 200 is valid, but 404 is certainly better and it is perfectly valid... We don't have to bind every URL matching a template to the collection resource, so we can leave out URLs which are out of range...

Comment: I've been using 404 for a while thanks to this answer. Now, I'm reconsidering. See my answer. (Not saying this is wrong, my answer just brings up a practical POV.)

Answer (score 4):

1. I don't think it is 400, because the request is valid, but there are REST APIs which use 400 by out of range errors.
2. 404 is valid if we say that we don't have to bind every URL matching the pagination template to the collection resource. By range headers style pagination it won't work, because by there pages share the same URL. By query style pagination it is valid.
3. The 200 with empty resource is valid. The requested page does not contain items.
4. 204 should be applied with empty message body. You probably want to send back links to the first and last pages of the collection, so this might not the solution you want.

So I think any of 200, 204 and 404 can be a valid solution.

- 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable - optionally we could use this, which has the exact meaning we want, but it should be applied only with range headers. *(note: should != must, English is a hard language :D)*

Answer (score 1):

I've been using 404 for a while, following [@PhilLab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724842/4653485), and now, I find it a bit inconsistent.

My API has default pagination parameters, so

```
api/products
```

translates internally into

```
api/products?page=1&pagesize=10
```

When there are no products, what should this return?

```
api/products
```

I find it weird to return a 404 for this URL as if it was an incorrect URL.

But technically, the request is out of range, so I find it inconsistent to return a 200 in this case (totalpages=0, page=1) and not in the general out of range case (totalpages=1, page=2). It makes the "0 element" case singular.

The point here is that using 404 for an out-of-range parametrized request and a 200 for an out-of-range unparametrized request (where pagination is done with default values) establishes a difference between both requests, while in the code, the unparametrized request is just injected default values when coming in and treated equally afterwards. The other layers of code don't need to know the pagination parameters are injected defaults.

Also, if the 200 response contains pagination metadata, the client gets more information with a 200 that includes the total number of items or pages than with a plain 404.

Finally, from a practical perspective, I also find it easier (less code) to return a 200.

Comment: interesting aspect. But lets leave REST for a moment and look at the statement ``print(someArray)`` vs ``print(someArray[100])``. The first one will also work for an empty array. But the second one will fail, if it is empty. I would accept the same behavior for REST: If I request the whole list, I get 200 OK even if it is empty. But if I request an element outside the range, I get an error message. Nevertheless, always returning 200 OK but just with an empty response if no elements are there as you suggest, is also a valid approach

Comment: Maybe this is more of an implementation issue on my side. I translate `/api/products` (1) into `/api/products?page=1&pagesize=10` (2) before doing anything. When the collection is empty, the code doesn't know if the user passed (1) or (2). Worse if the default page is not 1 (yeah, who would do that ?...), the default URL can be out of range on a non-empty collection. Just to illustrate the fact that the default parameter-less URL can be out-of-range but you don't want to return a 404 on this URL so you end up having to manage a special case for the default case, not just inject default values.